# Using an object as a parameter vs creating the object in the method

Tags: php, oop

During a discussion, I wasn't sure if I was correct when saying:

> "It's better to pass around objects as parameters instead of object
>   ID's."

So I thought I'd ask here for clarification.

What are the advantages of doing this:

```
public function doSomething(\Item $item) 
{   
     return $item->getSomething() * 2;
}
```

Over this:

```
public function doSomething($itemID) 
{
    $item = \Item::getByID($itemID); // Return an item based on ID
    if ($item) // Check the object has been returned
    {
       return $item->getSomething() * 2;
    }
}
```

Is it true to say that one benefit is you can presume the object will exist, so there is no need to check if it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection), and the main benefit is that you can test the `doSomething()` method in complete isolation by injecting a "`mock`" Item object into the method, so testing `doSomething()` isn't dependent on the logic of Item itself

Comment: Ah of course. Are there any other benefits unrelated to testability?

Comment: Other benefits, like you can pass object of class Item or of classes that extend class Item; whereas your second version forces you to instantiate an object of type Item unless you jump through some hoops in the getByID() method - that gives you additional flexibility.... that's the `L` of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design))

Answer (score 0):

The first solution may be a little bit faster at runtime. You should prefer that to the second inside of a loop. The second does a look up for the item by its ID.